# Swipe gesture does not function

Tags: android, actionscript-3, swipe-gesture

I am developing a mobile apps with swipe gesture. User need to swipe to the left in order to view the list of contents. Then,  when user click one of the content, there will be list of sub content and here is the problem. User supposedly can scroll the sub content, but this is not working. Here, I attached together with my [.fla](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c49s9l9beub0n02/HOMEPAGE4_1.fla?dl=0) and the coding I applied and Im developing the app by using Actionsript 3, Android Air.

Here is the coding I applied for the first swipe for my front page

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

SWIPE.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE, onSwipe);

function onSwipe(event:TransformGestureEvent): void
{

    if (event.offsetX == 1){
        SWIPE.x += 470;
        gotoAndPlay(2);
    }
    if (event.offsetX == -1)
    {
        SWIPE.x -= 470;
    }


}
```

While, for the coding below I applied for my sub topic swipe,

```
Multitouch.inputMode = MultitouchInputMode.GESTURE;

HOMEPAGE_MC.addEventListener(TransformGestureEvent.GESTURE_SWIPE , onSwipe1); 
function onSwipe1 (e:TransformGestureEvent):void
{
    if (e.offsetY == 1) 
    { 
    //User swiped towards bottom
    HOMEPAGE_MC.y += 251.7; 
    }
    if (e.offsetY == -1) 
    { 
    //User swiped towards top
    HOMEPAGE_MC.y -= 251.7;
    } 
}
```

Anyone please help me what should I alter..? Thank you.

Comment: If you want attention please post your code, not just a link. Some Good Samaritan may download it and look into it, but more casual helpers or answerers on their phones like me can't help you at all with a question like this void of actual code. Just a tip for you to get more responses.

Comment: Thank you for the tips given @NealDavis